# Are the numbers $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{p(n)}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{q(n)}$ transcendental?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, partitions, transcendental-number-theory

For each positive integer $n$, let $p(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ (i.e., the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of positive integers), and let $q(n)$ be the number of strict partitions of $n$ (i.e., the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of distinct positive integers).The integer sequences $p(n)\ (n=1,2,3,\ldots)$ and $q(n)\ (n=1,2,3,\ldots)$ are
available from http://oeis.org/A000041 and http://oeis.org/A000009, respectively. The famous Hardy-Ramanujan formula states that
$$p(n)\sim\frac{e^{\pi\sqrt{2n/3}}}{4\sqrt3}\qquad \ \text{as}\ \ n\to+\infty.$$
It is also known that $$q(n)\sim\frac{e^{\pi\sqrt{n/3}}}{4(3n^3)^{1/4}}\qquad \ \text{as}\ \ n\to+\infty.$$
Thus the two series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{p(n)}\quad\mbox{and}\quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{q(n)}$$
converge.

**Question.** Are the numbers
$$s=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{p(n)}\quad\mbox{and}\quad t=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{q(n)}$$
transcendental?

I conjecture that both $s$ and $t$ are transcendental numbers. Any way to prove this? If not, can one prove that $s$ and $t$ are irrational numbers?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: I conjecture that every number that isn't obviously algebraic is transcendental.

Comment: Can you define "obviously algebraic" in a rigorous mathematical manner?

Comment: I consider the question interesting since both $p(n)$ and $q(n)$ grow slower than exponenetial functions but faster than polynomials.

Comment: A lot of sequences grow slower than exponential but faster than polynomial.

Comment: Would you please provide me some examples of  such integer sequences as natural as $p(n)$ and $q(n)$?

Comment: Can you define "natural" in a rigorous mathematical manner?

Comment: I'm unwilling to argue with anybody. Of course, you have your right to think that transcendence  problems like Hilbert's 7th Problem are not interesting. I regret  my posting.

Comment: I hope that editors could close this posting.

Comment: I never said transcendence problems are not interesting. I never said Hilbert's 7th problem was not interesting. I think that before you conjecture that some particular number is transcendental, you might want to have some reason for making that conjecture. And if the only reason is that almost all numbers are transcendental, then it's not clear why one picks out that particular number for special attention.

Comment: I think many people will think that $p(n)$ is more interesting than $2^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}$. There are lots of research papers on the partition function.

Comment: I don't want to waste time in arguing. It's okay for me to delete this question.

Comment: If you want to delete your question, you don't need to wait for someone to do it, you can do it yourself. But I'm not calling for it. No one has even voted to close the question, and I haven't given it a downvote, so there's no reason I can see for deleting it. I'm just expressing my feeling that this sort of question is generally hopeless, unless there is some concrete proposal for making some progress on it, and I'm not seeing any such proposal.

Comment: I see you've already added comments at https://oeis.org/A078506 and https://oeis.org/A237515